# "Not in" membership caml query

Tags: caml-query

In a custom list definition, I'm building a view with this query :

```
      <Where>
          <Or>
            <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
              <FieldRef Name="MyUserField" />
            </Membership>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="MyUserField" />
              <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID Type="Integer" />
              </Value>
            </Eq>
          </Or>
      </Where>
```

As you guessed, the idea is to show only items if the field `MyUserField` contains the current user or a group where the user is a member.

Now I would like to change my query to restrict the display to users that are **not** designated (directly or via membership) in a second group.

I don't see any definition nor for a `Not` operation in Caml, neither for a `NotMembership`. This is not working :

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
                <FieldRef Name="MyUserField" />
            </Membership>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="MyUserField" />
                <Value Type="Integer">
                    <UserID Type="Integer" />
                </Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Not>
            <Or>
                <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
                    <FieldRef Name="MyUserField2" />
                </Membership>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="MyUserField2" />
                    <Value Type="Integer">
                        <UserID Type="Integer" />
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
        </Not>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran a query on a list in [SP CAML Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) and I got results with this:

```
            <Query>
                <Where>
                    <And>
                        <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
                            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
                        </Membership>
                        <Neq>
                            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
                            <Value Type="Integer">
                                <UserID Type="Integer" />
                            </Value>
                        </Neq>
                    </And>
                </Where>
            </Query>
```

Using Eq I returned 0 results and using Neq I returned 1 result.  This seems to what you are looking for.  (Although almost a year late!)

Comment: Wouldn't this return the entry if the user is in the group in the field but not directly in the field?

Comment: This doesn't work